# Получить время до 1900

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $day = '1';
    $month = '3';
    $year = '1994';
    $born = date(mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
    echo date('d.n.Y', $born);
?>
```

Получаю `762458400` и `1.3.1994`

```
<?php
    $day = '17';
    $month = '1';
    $year = '1962';
    $born = date(mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
    echo date('d.n.Y', $born);
?>
```

Получаю `-251078400` и `16.12.1977`
должно быть `17.1.1962`

Есть другое решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно чего именно хочется, потому как вот это:

```
17.1.1962
```

Получается элементарно:

```
echo "$day.$month.$year";
```

Можно посмотреть в сторону [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php), например:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', "$month/$day/$year");
echo $date->format('F j, Y'); // Janyary 17, 1962
```

Но нужно быть готовым к тому, что:

```
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Выведет `-251050001`. Фактически в этом и причина всех бед: ЕМНИП, только Windows не умеет работать с отрицательными значениями timestamp, и для этой ОС приходится делать костыли. У других с этим всё нормально:

```
$  cat ./d.php && uname && ./d.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$day = '17';
$month = '1';
$year = '1962';
$tstamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
$born = date( $tstamp );
echo "$tstamp <=> ".date('d.n.Y', $born);

Linux

-251089200 <=> 17.1.1962
```

Comment: Спасибо DateTime помогло!